# Other inverse binomial

Tags: probability

An urn contains $x$ balls. We know that $p\%$ are red and $(1-p)\%$ are blue.
We draw without replacement $n$ balls and get $n_1$ red balls.
What is the probability that $x=k$ ?

Same question if we draw the $n$ balls with replacement.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of the question, utilize the **Hypergeometric Distribution**. Please allow me to modify your question a little.

> The urn has $N$ balls, of which $p$ of them are red and $(N-p)$ of them are blue. After drawing $k$ balls (where $k \leq N$), $n$ of them are red balls (where $n \leq p$). What is the probability that $n = (k-p),  (k-p+1), (k-p+2), ..., min(k, p)$ ?

The link for hypergeometric is [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricDistribution.html).

For the second part of the question, you should use the **Negative Binomial Distribution**.
The link is [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialDistribution.html).

Comment: Not sure that this is the answer to my question.

For example, with my notation, what is the answer if
P=0.6
n=50
n1=20

What is le probability that x=100 and how do you compute it?

Comment: the thing is, $x$ is the total number of balls in the urn. So $x$ can never be $k$ unless $k=x$. You might want to review your question again with different notation.